# What good is setPrototypeOf(...) when both arguments are constructor names only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

This is a question about javascript prototyping, but it arises from my reading of the node.js source code, specifically at lines 281-282 (Chrome browser Win10) in:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js#L281

Those lines are:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(ClientRequest.prototype, OutgoingMessage.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(ClientRequest, OutgoingMessage);
```

I understand the first line - standard approach to ensure ClientRequest objects have OutgoingMessage prototype properties in their prototype chain.

The second line is stranger.  Since both parameters need to be objects, then in this case, those objects are Function objects.  So this seems to be saying the prototype of Function object 'ClientRequest' is set equal to the Function object 'OutgoingMessage'.

Not sure what this does for us, thanks for any comments on it.

Comment: inherits static methods, mostly, but is also just how `class` works